# How to crop this image?

Tags: php, image

I have this image,



[image]

I want to crop this image to several sizes, for that i use this function-

```
function thumbanail_for_image($Id, $newfilename, $size=NULL) {

    $file_extension = substr($newfilename, strrpos($newfilename, '.') + 1);
    $arr = explode('.', $newfilename);

    $thumb1 = LOCAL_FOLDER . $arr[0] . "_" . $Id . "." . $file_extension;
    $thumb2 = LOCAL_FOLDER . $arr[0] . "_" . $Id . "b" . "." . $file_extension;

    $old = LOCAL_FOLDER . $newfilename;

    $newfilename = LOCAL_FOLDER . $newfilename;

    $srcImage = "";

    $sizee = getimagesize($newfilename);

    switch ($sizee['mime']) {
    case "image/jpeg" :
        $srcImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($old);
        break;
    case "image/png":
        $srcImage = imagecreatefrompng($old);
        break;
    case "image/gif":
        $srcImage = imagecreatefromgif($old);
        break;
    }
    $srcwidth = $sizee[0];
    $srcheight = $sizee[1];

    if ($srcwidth > $srcheight || $srcwidth < $srcheight) {
    $destwidth1 = 65;
    $rat = $destwidth1 / $srcwidth;
    $destheight1 = (int) ($srcheight * $rat);
    }

    elseif ($srcwidth == $srcheight) {
    $destwidth1 = 65;
    $destheight1 = 65;
    }

    if ($srcwidth > $srcheight || $srcwidth < $srcheight) {
    $destwidth2 = 300;
    $rat = $destwidth2 / $srcwidth;
    $destheight2 = (int) ($srcheight * $rat);
    }
    elseif ($srcwidth == $srcheight) {
    $destwidth2 = 300;
    $destheight2 = 300;
    }

    $destImage1 = imagecreatetruecolor($destwidth1, $destheight1);
    $destImage2 = imagecreatetruecolor($destwidth2, $destheight2);

    imagecopyresampled($destImage1, $srcImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $destwidth1, $destheight1, $srcwidth, $srcheight);
    imagecopyresampled($destImage2, $srcImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $destwidth2, $destheight2, $srcwidth, $srcheight);

    if ($sizee['mime'] == "image/jpeg") {
    imagejpeg($destImage1, $thumb1, 80);
    imagejpeg($destImage2, $thumb2, 80);
    } elseif ($sizee['mime'] == "image/png") {
    imagepng($destImage1, $thumb1, 80);
    imagepng($destImage2, $thumb2, 80);
    } elseif ($sizee['mime'] == "image/gif") {
    imagegif($destImage1, $thumb1, 80);
    imagegif($destImage2, $thumb2, 80);
    }
    imagedestroy($destImage1);
    imagedestroy($destImage2);
    chmod($destImage1, 0777);
    chmod($destImage2, 0777);
    return $destImage1;
}
```

LOCAL_FOLDER is variable path to local

The problem i saw is when i print $_FILES info about it shows

```
[type] =>image/jpeg
```

and when i print getimagesize() function it prints

```
[mime] => image/png
```

Please help,
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not use a lib that handles all these things for you?

For instance, check out [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/):

```
include "path-to/WideImage.php";


$image = WideImage::load("path-to/image.jpg");
$cropped = $image->crop(0, 0, 100, 50);
$cropped->saveToFile("cropped-image.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [POST method uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) page says:

> **$_FILES['userfile']['type']**
>
> The mime type of the file, if the browser provided this information.
> An example would be "image/gif". This mime type is however not checked
> on the PHP side and therefore don't take its value for granted.

So the image type data here is provided by the client that uploaded the file, and PHP recommends don't trust it.  Trust what `getimagesize()` gives you instead.